# Why Kafka care about the hostname?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python

I did a test with code below to send data to topic. The kafka is

```
kafka_2.12-1.1.0
```

The code are

```
import kafka
print(kafka.version.__version__)
from kafka import KafkaProducer 
producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers=['172.25.44.238:9092'],
    sasl_mechanism="PLAIN",
    api_version=(0, 10),
    retries=2
)
f = producer.send("test", "some")
f.get()
```

If I change the server config like this:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://172.25.44.238:9092
```

Then my code can send data to my topic

If I change the server config like this which is default:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

Then my code will hit error:

```
kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Batch for TopicPartition(topic='test', partition=0) containing 1 record(s) expired: 30 seconds have passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

The difference is that the sencond will use hostname by default. And yes my machine running the producer code can not reslove the kafka hostname. But I did not use the hostname in producer code either. So it should not cause the error. So why the hostname matter?

Comment: Where do you get "the second will use hostname by default"? I was pretty sure it would use `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the concept of "bootstrapping".

The address you provide only establishes initial connection. The address the clients **actually** use is defined by the `advertised.listeners`.

The `listeners` should always be `://0.0.0.0`, in my opinion, then you use OS level firewall settings to restrict access. Yes, the default is the hostname, and this means only that host can communicate with the broker

Comment: Not really - it's perfectly valid to configure several listeners, [for example in a Docker setup](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/).

Comment: @daniu `listeners` should always be `0.0.0.0`... There is never a reason to use the Docker service name as the [bind address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0#As_a_host_address).  **`advertised.listeners`** should always point to a resolvable address by any potential client .

Comment: Hm, then why does theconfiguration item exist in the first place? I was assuming it was supposed to be used to limit access, eg for security reasons. Wouldn't I need to configure two non-`0.0.0.0` interfaces if I get inbound traffic from one subnet and route traffic into another?

Comment: @daniu IMO, you can use OS-level firewalls to limit interfaces. Sure, you can use `listeners=192.168.0.0` to bind to that subnet, but that's not very common